# Scroll horizontally to middle of the page on page load

Tags: html, css, center, centering

[This page here](http://2vsk.liepaja.edu.lv/Tenses/index.php) needs to start in the middle, where it says "Present". Not on the left, where it starts now. Is ti doable?

Last one I've found is this -

```
 <script> function pageScroll() { window.scrollTo(2000,0); scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100);} //Increase this # to slow down, decrease to speed up scrolling } //--> </script>
```

`<body onload="pageScroll()">` But it forces my page to constantly return to center. I need the center view on page load only. Later on, the user should be able to move left or right freely.

Comment: Did some research. None worked.

Comment: ..and how did you demonstrate this "research"?

Comment: Are you coding an actual page or just using the image? Either way, just wrap the whole thing in a DIV and offset its position by ~50%.

Comment: @Paulie_D Last one I've found is
<script>
function pageScroll() 
{ window.scrollTo(2000,0); scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100);} //Increase this # to slow down, decrease to speed up scrolling } //--> </script>

<body onload="pageScroll()">

But it forces my page to constantly return to center. I need the center view on page load only. Later on, the user should be able to move left or right freely.

Comment: @ecg8 Can you elaborate on that? I'm trying to wrap the thing with #mainArea {
 margin:auto;
 width: 5337px;
 position:relative;
 margin-bottom:1%;   
 }

But the page still loads on the uttermost left.

Answer (score 0):

This script should do it. Works in Edge, Firefox, while fails in Chrome (report is sent).

```
function pageScroll() {window.scrollTo(x,y);}   //set x,y to desired pixel value
```